# How can I push an iterator to an existing vector (or any other collection)?

Tags: collections, rust, iterator

Looking through the documentation or Rust 0.12, I saw [the following method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push_all) to push multiple values to an already existing `Vec`:

```
fn push_all(&mut self, other: &[T])
```

However, if I have an iterator, I don't think it is efficient to use: `vector.push_all(it.collect().as_ref())`. Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `Vec`'s [`extend` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html). `extend` takes a value of any type that implements `IntoIterator` (which includes all iterator types) and extends the `Vec` by all elements returned from the iterator:

```
vector.extend(it)
```

Since `extend` belongs to the `Extend` trait, it also works for many other collection types.